# PHP: convert array to function argument list

Tags: php, call, variadic-functions

Is it possible to convert the array in `_call` to a function argument list in some way and get the code to work?

```
abstract class FooClass {

  protected function foo() {

    $args = func_get_args();

    $listIndex = 0;

    foreach ($args as $arg) {

      echo ++$listIndex . ": " . $arg . "\n";

    }

  }

}

class BarClass extends FooClass {

  public function __call($name, $arguments) {

    if (strcmp($name, 'foo') == 0) {

      $this->$name(list($arguments));

    }

    die("Unexpected method.");

  }

}

$barInstance = new BarClass;

$barInstance->foo("one", "two", "three", "four");
```

Comment: Have you considered `call_user_func_array`?http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: $this->$name(list($arguments)); -> $this->foo(list($arguments)); for this case? 'unexpected method' will always be hit

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.6 you can also use [variadics](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: @Machavity, I think PHP 5.6 is too new for what I'm looking for, some servers may not support it yet and I don't want my code to stop working once I upload it. But thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as it turns out, what I was asking for is possible. Here is the fixed code:

```
abstract class FooClass {

  protected function foo() {

    $args = func_get_args();

    $listIndex = 0;

    foreach ($args as $arg) {

      echo ++$listIndex . ": " . $arg . "\n";

    }

  }

  protected function fooz() {

    echo "\nDone!\n";

  }

}

class BarClass extends FooClass {

  public function __call($name, $arguments) {

    if (in_array($name, array('foo', 'fooz'))) {

      call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);

    } else {

      die("Unexpected method.");

    }

  }

}

$barInstance = new BarClass;

$barInstance->foo("one", "two", "three", "four");
$barInstance->fooz();
```

and here is the output:

```
1: one
2: two
3: three
4: four

Done!
```